# Why can't the AD be located at the top of the screen in android Tabbed activity?

Tags: android

I create a tabbed activity, and I have set the AD named android:id="@+id/adView" located at the top of screen using android:layout_alignParentTop="true".

After I run the app, I find the four tabs are located at the top of the screen. How can I make the AD located at the above of Tab? Thanks!

**Current**

[image]

**I hope**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:paddingTop="12dip"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingRight="7dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adView=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        SetAD(adView);


        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public  void SetAD(AdView adView) {
        if (true) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }else{
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragment1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragment1();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
            }

            //set args if necessary
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(PlaceholderFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number1";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


            return rootView;
        }
    }



    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment1 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment1 newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment1 fragment = new PlaceholderFragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment1() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main1, container, false);

            Button cw= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAA);

            final LayoutInflater my=inflater;
            cw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Toast.makeText(my.getContext(), "CW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't really give the complete code as for now but if you do know the concept of Toolbars, it might help you cause toolbar once created in a different layout, can be used in any of your parent layouts using the <include> tag. Now, that toolbar can be placed anywhere in the screen you want so it might help you achieve what you are planning to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your layout is inside an ActionbarActivity and when you set your layout it will always within the action bar (in you case the titlebar and tabs).
To achieve what you want create your own custom titlebar and tabs.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a sample about how to create a custom titlebar and tabs?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-1:**

If you want to align Tabbar at top of the screen and get rid of `ActionBar`, You can try this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Add these both items in your `styles.xml` under `res/values` folder to remove actionbar from Activity.

Also you have to set theme for this activity in `manifest` like below:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

**Solution-2:**

Consider using `ToolBar` , that way you can easily position your tabs in layout. [here is link to use Toolbar](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: Thanks! parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" require API 11, but my min API is 9

Comment: @HelloCW: In that case, consider using theme supporting you minSdk.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ActionBar` seems doesn't has any menu item. So it's possible to hide the `ActionBar` and place the ad on top of the `Tab`. In your MainActivity, call:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

And your layout for `activity_main` should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Consider using `Toolbar`, and you will found a better way. And if you are using `Toolbar`, your layout should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! but the Tabs (SECTION1, SECTION2, SECTION3, SECTION4) are hided when I try to use your way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create and manage a layout for the tabs, so you're free to place it where needed: if you use actionbar's tabs, they will be placed under the AB. See for example this [solution](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html). I believe it is under the sdk samples folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need custom tab layout. For example you can use ready-to-use solution [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). 
Your main layout will be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/page_indicator"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Bind indicator to your ViewPager

```
//Set the pager with an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

//Bind the title indicator to the adapter
TabPageIndicator tabIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
tabIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```